# Sum to infinity of An and Sk

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ for which $S_k = \frac{k + 1}{k}$ $\forall k 
\in \mathbb N$. Find $A_n$ and the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

I think i have worked out that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is $1$. But i don't know how to work out $A_n$ or show fully how i got my answer for the sum to infinity.

$S_k=\frac{k+1}{k}$

hence $\lim_{k\to \infty} S_k=1$.

which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is $1$.

Comment: Hi, I edited your question. Please see if I accidentally  chenged your meaning. BTW, what is the relationship between $S_k$ and $A_n$?

Comment: Thank you for editing it. The meaning hasn't changed. Sk is a sequence of partial sums of An.

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k.
$$
If you have really proved that
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \frac{n+1}{n}
$$
for every $k$, then your conclusion is perfectly legitimate, since $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n+1}{n}=1$.

Comment: Thank you. How do i find An though?

Comment: Well, $a_n = s_n-s_{n-1}$, just by canceling out all the terms except the last one.

Comment: Come on, it's elementary algebra!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right trace. You should know that the sum is the limit of $S_k$. And $A_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$a_k=S_k-S_{k-1} \text{   for  } k\gt1$$